# Android video stream calculate frame rate or video streaming speed

Tags: android, video-streaming, frame-rate

I want to calculate video speed on android. I have found that it is dependent of frame rate.
How can I calculate streaming video from some url and calculate its frame rate in android application?

Comment: I am sorry to use research word but it does not mean that I am getting help for my research. I have search on internet and I did not get my answer. I was thinking that internet initiate to share information between scientists. So why not stack overflow share information.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42204944/how-to-get-frame-rate-of-video-in-android-os