# how to get frame rate of video in android os?

Tags: java, android, video, frame-rate

I want to get frame rate of video, but i don't want to use FFMPEG,JAVACV lib.
is that possible to get frame rate of video in android?

I read [KEY_FRAME_RATE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaFormat.html#KEY_FRAME_RATE) it's says that,"Specifically, MediaExtractor provides an integer value corresponding to the frame rate information of the track if specified and non-zero."
but i don't know how to use it?

if you know about how to get frame rate from video then answer here.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
MediaExtractor extractor = new MediaExtractor();
int frameRate = 24; //may be default
try {
  //Adjust data source as per the requirement if file, URI, etc.
  extractor.setDataSource(...);
  int numTracks = extractor.getTrackCount();
  for (int i = 0; i < numTracks; ++i) {
    MediaFormat format = extractor.getTrackFormat(i);
    String mime = format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);
    if (mime.startsWith("video/")) {
    if (format.containsKey(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE)) {
        frameRate = format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE);
      }
    }
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}finally {
  //Release stuff
  extractor.release();
}
```

**Note:** Try to run the above code in worker thread.

**Update 1** What is **KEY_FRAME_RATE** and may be **optional**

> **KEY_FRAME_RATE** 
>   Added in API level 16
>   String KEY_FRAME_RATE
>   A key describing the frame rate of a video format in frames/sec. The associated value is normally an integer when the value is used by the platform, but video codecs also accept float configuration values. Specifically, MediaExtractor provides an integer value corresponding to the frame rate information of the track if specified and non-zero. **Otherwise, this key is not present.** MediaCodec accepts both float and integer values. This represents the desired operating frame rate if the KEY_OPERATING_RATE is not present and KEY_PRIORITY is 0 (realtime). For video encoders this value corresponds to the intended frame rate, although encoders are expected to support variable frame rate based on buffer timestamp. This key is not used in the MediaCodec input/output formats, nor by MediaMuxer.

Constant Value: "frame-rate"

**Update 2** Code check if for NPE if KEY_FRAME_RATE not present. See above

Comment: it throw `NullPointerException` at format.getString(MediaFormat.KEY_MIME);

Comment: Post the log for the same. But how it can be if it is going inside for loop?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
02-16 19:19:21.741: E/fra(7900):  at android.media.MediaFormat.getInteger(MediaFormat.java:591)
02-16 19:19:21.741: E/fra(7900):  at com.exam.activity.VideoPlayActivity.init(VideoPlayActivity.java:101)
02-16 19:19:21.741: E/fra(7900):  at com.exam.activity.VideoPlayActivity.onCreate(VideoPlayActivity.java:59)

Comment: What is the android OS version on which you are testing upon? Also try posting the value of format.containsKey(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE). You can log this before String mime. And the exception is on this format.getInteger line.

Comment: android 6.0  , kernal version 3.10.72+

Comment: Did you get it after I have updated my answer above?

Comment: I used 
`format.getInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE);`
and `format.getFloat(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE);`

both option

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135922/discussion-between-anurag-singh-and-prakash-u).

Comment: KEY_FRAME_RATE seems to have a complicated path... especially around Lollipop. Check out [this table](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.html#isFormatSupported(android.media.MediaFormat)) under the `isFormatSupported(format)` method. I've had to do some clever coding to avoid issues with it.

Comment: @eatcrayons Thanks for the update. Will extend this answer in time to add support for the same. What clever coding did you do?

Comment: @AnuragSingh I do a version check. If it's Lollipop, I save the KEY_FRAME_RATE from the `MediaFormat` object to a temp variable and replace it with null. Then I make my call to `isFormatSupported(format)`. Finally, I place the saved KEY_FRAME_RATE back into the `MediaFormat` object.

Comment: why we can't init MediaExtractor only once and release after for example 10 files like with MediaMetadataRetriever?