# How to get current frame number from video in android?

Tags: android

Is there a way to get the current frame number of the video while video is playing, or when the video has paused? using videoview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the VideoWiew, you can retrieve the playback time in milliseconds with [`getCurrentPosition`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/VideoView#getCurrentPosition()). Then you have to make some calculations based on the frame rate of the video itself, for which I invite you to read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42204944/how-to-get-frame-rate-of-video-in-android-os).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get it by calling getCurrentPosition() on your videoView. Such as(videoView.getCurrentPosition). and place that inside a pause button or something along those lines.

getCurrentPosition() – *Returns an integer value indicating the current position of playback.*

Source: https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Kotlin_Android_Video_Playback_using_the_VideoView_and_MediaController_Classes